# icon left or right side the button?

Tags: buttons, icons

Why is the icon placed on the right side of the button in some designs and on the left side in other cases?

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When a button contains text and an icon, which should come first?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/when-a-button-contains-text-and-an-icon-which-should-come-first)

Answer (score 1):

The icon should always be displayed before the text for a better association between the icon and the label and this also depends on the direction of your text.

- **RTL (right to left) -> icon on the right**
- **LTR (left to right) -> icon on the left**

Interesting use case of the drop-down menu arrow, I advise you to put it at the end of the label.